# Vector field of a magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vector-fields, magnetic-moment

Given a standard reference system with axes x y z representing a 3 dimensional space and given a magnet whose north and south pole are at points $P_N=(x_N,y_N,z_N)$ and $P_S=(x_S,y_S,z_S)$ what is the law that describes the vector field of the magnet at any other point of the space? I'm interested in the law that associates to each point $P=(x,y,z) $ the direction and modulus of the vector of the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal dipole  magnet has a $1/R^2$ field directed toward the S pole, plus
a $1/R^2$ field away from the N pole.  The vector sum of those
two field elements is the field of the dipole.
The Earth's North pole is attractive to the N pole of a magnet, and (confusingly)
is thus a S pole.

$${\mathrm {
\vec {B} = {(\vec P_S - \vec P) \over {|(\vec P_S -\vec P)| ^3} }  - {(\vec P_N -\vec P) \over {|\vec P_N - \vec P|}^3} }
}$$

Comment: What is $R $ ? Could you give some reference please?

Comment: R  is displacement from the point (the pole) to the measurement location.   I'm using R as the general indicator of distance, as though it were a spherical radial-distance coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

[Biot Savart](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law), or if idealize the situation, [Ampere's law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/amplaw.html)
Imagine a magnet as a current loop rotating around the north direction (right hand's rule)

Comment: Sampling the values of $\vec{B}$ for a set of points along a path how would you guess the positions of the poles?